# How to make a border-radius stop becoming wholly rounded when only two sides?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to use HTML / CSS / JS to create an animation-type thing similar to [this gif](https://gyazo.com/9be5fa1f2a7bc14fcb5fa0c1605dbc06). I'm using ::before and ::after to create two 'half-circles' with border-radius: 50%, but I noticed that even with two borders removed, it will still taper off around the element. It's quite hard to explain, but [this is it](http://prntscr.com/fy7tls), and I'm sure you can see what I mean.

Here is a snippet:

```css
.animation-container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.animation-container::before, .animation-container::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.animation-container::before {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
}

.animation-container::after {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Tests Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="animation-container"></div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a special reason you're using animations? A gif is actually a *lot* more efficient than an animation in this scenario... Anyway, you can't prevent tapering since that's the logical thing to happen with an effect such as border-radius...

Maybe you could use something like this, though?

https://jsfiddle.net/vocfgfjn/1/

*HTML:*

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 #000 transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 0;
}
```

Comment: He want half of the circle, you should put `border-color:#000 #000 transparent transparent;` instead

Comment: I'm using animations because I need to be able to change the speed and colour easily, and I can't design graphics to save my life :)

Comment: Nice solution. So the tapering is caused by setting the border width, as opposed to the border color/transparency? [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/vocfgfjn/2/)
 combining yours with Arthur's animation.

Comment: @showdev Nice, you pretty much finished it. Great job!

Comment: @Babydead no, I haven't tried it, thanks for the link, and thanks for the solution! :)

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about creating your half-circle like that ?

```css
.half-circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: rotateAnim 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.half-circle:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #FFF;
}
@keyframes rotateAnim {
    from {transform: rotate(0);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need the background to be transparent :(

Comment: Even if I post this answer I think the @Babydead 's one is better ;)

Comment: @Arthur lol, I actually think your answer was better, but thank you :)